# Building new Android App Bundle fails with aapt

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to setup building the new Android App Bundles via Gradle. I'm building with this command:

```
./gradlew bundleLiveDebug
```

(`live` is my flavor)

The build always fails with:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleLiveDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

I read in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/build) that it requires `aapt2` and it should be enabled via `android.enableAapt2=true` in `gradle.properties`, but the error is the same.

Comment: What's the error are you getting?

Comment: Why are you using `bundleLiveDebug`? 
Can you make sure that  `./gradlew clean` and `./gradlew bundleDebug` are working or not?

Comment: @sam_k The error is written in the post. Clean works. I can't use bundleDebug because I have two flavors, flavor (live) needs to be specified.

Comment: You're just giving the highest-level error. If you look at the build log there will be the actual errors from aapt2. They should be just above the stacktrace and should start with "Error:" or "AAPT:"

Comment: I have already solved it, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Android App Bundle feature requires Android Gradle Plugin version 3.2.0+, I had version 3.1.2